# Bitnami Mongodb timeout from local network

Tags: linux, mongodb, database-connection, vmware, bitnami

I setup a vmware ESXI 7.0.2 on a server machine.

In Vmware i installed a bitnami mongodb virtual machine [Using this link](https://bitnami.com/stack/mongodb/virtual-machine)
With mongodb console, i'm able to reach mongodb within vmware ESXI using the following command: `mongo admin --username root -p`
When i log in, everything works fine.

From now on, i want to reach this mongodb from an other machine on the same network with the following connection string: `mongodb://192.168.10.110:27017`

In order to reach it, iam using **MongoDB Compass** and initiating a **New Connection**.
Even if i put the credentials into the connection string ( which iam using to log in to mongodb from bitnami console ) like this: `mongodb://[username]:[password]192.168.10.110:27017` the connection is timed out always.

In the bitnami console, when i start the virtual machine, the console says that i can reach it with this IP, which is from DHCP.

Picture included:

[image]

If i log in to mongo i see this on the console:

[image]

So i can connect to mongodb within bitnami console, but not from outside VMWARE but inside the same network.

**EDIT:** *Tried using with NodeJS from the same machine which runs MongoDB Compass, but this results in a timeout too.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that i had to open the port for the mongodb to be able to access it from "outside" it's network.

I just went and enabled the firewall first:

```
sudo systemctl enable ufw
sudo ufw status
```

started it:

```
sudo systemctl start ufw
```

and opened the port

```
sudo ufw allow 27017
```

**All is working fine. My bad.**